# Table within a table woes (libgdx)

Tags: java, libgdx

I am making a GUI for a card game, working with libgdx for the first time.  I am a CS student, relatively inexperienced programmer.

The idea is that I have a screen where I select my character type, and when I select the character the correct skill tree fills in a table on the right side of the screen depending on which character was chosen.

I am putting all of the character skill trees into separate classes, simply for separation of code since otherwise it would get super long.

my show method:

```
    public void show() {
    skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("data/uiskin.json"));
    stage = new Stage();
    classList = new Table();
    confirmTable = new Table();
    skillTree = new Table();
    info = new Label("Class Selection", skin);

    masterTable = new Table();


    //CLASSLIST STUFF
    knight = new TextButton("knight", skin);
    healer = new TextButton("healer", skin);
    summoner = new TextButton("summoner", skin);
    wizard = new TextButton("wizard", skin);
    infiltrator = new TextButton("infiltrator", skin);
    mercenary = new TextButton("mercenary", skin);
    assassin = new TextButton("assassin", skin);
    trader = new TextButton("trader", skin);

    classList.add(knight).width(200).height(55).row();
    classList.add(healer).width(200).height(55).row();
    classList.add(summoner).width(200).height(55).row();
    classList.add(wizard).width(200).height(55).row();
    classList.add(infiltrator).width(200).height(55).row();
    classList.add(mercenary).width(200).height(55).row();
    classList.add(assassin).width(200).height(55).row();
    classList.add(trader).width(200).height(55).row();

    //CONFIRM TABLE STUFF
    confirm = new TextButton("Confirm Selection", skin);
    points = new Label("X/3 possible classes selected \nXX/XX points left unspent", skin);

    confirmTable.add(points).height(100).row();
    confirmTable.add(confirm).expand();


    //LOADED SKILLTREE
    skillTree.add(SoldierTree.soldier).expand();



    //LOAD TABLES INTO MASTER TABLE
    masterTable.add(classList).width(300).height(500).expand();
    masterTable.add(skillTree).width(900).height(500).expand();
    masterTable.row();
    masterTable.add(confirmTable).width(300).height(220).expand();
    masterTable.add(info).width(900).height(220).expand();
    masterTable.setFillParent(true);
    masterTable.setDebug(true);


    stage.addActor(masterTable);

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
}
```

and my SoldierTree

```
public class SoldierTree {

private static Skin skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("data/uiskin.json"));



public static Table soldier = new Table();

private static Table left = new Table();
private static Table middle = new Table();
private static Table right = new Table();

public static TextButton weapButton = new TextButton("weap", skin);
private static Label weapLabel = new Label("0/X", skin);

private static TextButton shieldButton = new TextButton("weap", skin);
private static Label shieldLabel = new Label("0/X", skin);

private static TextButton twoHanderButton = new TextButton("weap", skin);
private static Label twoHanderLabel = new Label("0/X", skin);

private static TextButton card1Button = new TextButton("weap", skin);
private static Label card1Label = new Label("0/X", skin);


private static TextButton healthButton = new TextButton("weap", skin);
private static Label healthLabel = new Label("0/X", skin);

private static TextButton armorButton = new TextButton("weap", skin);
private static Label armorLabel = new Label("0/X", skin);

private static TextButton pResistButton = new TextButton("weap", skin);
private static Label pResistLabel = new Label("0/X", skin);

private static TextButton card2Button = new TextButton("weap", skin);
private static Label card2Label = new Label("0/X", skin);

private static TextButton card3Button = new TextButton("weap", skin);
private static Label card3Label = new Label("0/X", skin);


private static TextButton staminaButton = new TextButton("weap", skin);
private static Label staminaLabel = new Label("0/X", skin);

private static TextButton sRegenButton = new TextButton("weap", skin);
private static Label sRegenLabel = new Label("0/X", skin);

private static TextButton card4Button = new TextButton("weap", skin);
private static Label card4Label = new Label("0/X", skin);

private static TextButton attackCostButton = new TextButton("weap", skin);
private static Label attackCostLabel = new Label("0/X", skin);

private static TextButton card5Button = new TextButton("weap", skin);
private static Label card5Label = new Label("0/X", skin);

public SoldierTree() {
    left.add(weapButton);
    left.add(weapLabel).row();
    left.add(weapButton);
    left.add(weapLabel).row();
    left.add(weapButton);
    left.add(weapLabel);
    left.add(weapButton);
    left.add(weapLabel);

    middle.add(healthButton);
    middle.add(healthLabel).row();
    middle.add(healthButton);
    middle.add(healthLabel);
    middle.add(healthButton);
    middle.add(healthLabel).row();
    middle.add(healthButton);
    middle.add(healthLabel).row();
    middle.add(healthButton);
    middle.add(healthLabel);

    right.add(staminaButton);
    right.add(staminaLabel).row();
    right.add(staminaButton);
    right.add(staminaLabel).row();
    right.add(staminaButton);
    right.add(staminaLabel).row();
    right.add(staminaButton);
    right.add(staminaLabel);
    right.add(staminaButton);
    right.add(staminaLabel);

    soldier.add(left).width(300).height(500).expand();
    soldier.add(middle).width(300).height(500).expand();
    soldier.add(right).width(300).height(500).expand();
}
```

}

edit:

while typing this out I have realized what I did wrong.  SoldierTree.soldier is static but the table isn't loaded up with stuff unless I call Soldier's constructor.  But in that case, how would I go about structuring this correctly?  I feel like this is a sloppy way to do this in general.  But is it reasonable to do this this way, and then in the original class just make a new SoldierTree (and WizardTree and HealerTree and whatever other characters there are), that way I can call up their tables whenever I want?

Comment: It's really unclear what you're actually asking. Do you have a specific question? A few comments on your code...Don't load a new skin in your SoldierTree class when you can reuse the one in your higher level class. Avoid public static members whenever possible as they make debugging much more difficult. It doesn't make sense for SoldierTree to have all those static members that are used by instances of SoldierTree. If you ever instantiated a second SoldierTree, you'd have an explosion of bugs.

Comment: Yeah sorry I know my question is unclear.  I had a specific question but I figured it out after I had typed everything out but then I didn't want to waste the effort.

You touch on my question at the end here.  How do I design this better?  I do want my skill trees to be static classes, or rather I want the tables to be static, and I want their code to be separated from my main class for readability, but I don't know how to do that without putting them in some class I have to instantiate.

And thanks for the advice about the skin, that makes sense but I didn't know that.

Comment: Am I unable to upvote you and then mark this as closed?  I regret posting it now, lol.  I recall this place being pretty strict about what is posted.

Comment: I don't care about upvotes, and anyway they don't count for anything on comments. You might want to check out the Code Review stack exchange site. Much less strict. And the Libgdx forum.